# How to decrease total number of the database hits in C# entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, query-optimization

I've implemented a data-driven localization in my own CMS using the entity framework.

Currently, to read a localization value from the database, I create a new EF context, connect to the database and read the value, so the total number of the database hits is a lot.

How can I decrease the total number of hits to the database?

Comment: Implement UnitOfWork Design Pattern For Handel connection.

Comment: Thanks Soheil, I handled it with UOW pattern. awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with Unit of work pattern.

Simple implementation of that you can check int this article of Radu Pascal: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/243914/Entity-Framework-context-per-request

Comment: Yes, I used your answer and UOW was awesome, however, I used caching mechanism which had a great performance and made the solution faster.